# Trying to get a picture and text side by side inside a div

Tags: html, css

I've been searching around for this and found a lot of similar cases but for whatever reason, the solution doesn't work in my scenario.

The text and picture are being stacked on top of each other. I'm having trouble keeping it inside the headerBlock div but side by side.

```css
#wrap { 
  width: 800px; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

#headerBlock { 
  height: 200px; 
  background:  #776b68; 
}

div.headerText {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: justify;
}

div.headerImg img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="headerBlock">
    <div class="headerText">Some text here</div>
    <div class="headerImg"><img src="/somepicturehere">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--Ignore these, it's for future use-->
  <div id="leftBlock"></div>

  <div id="rightBlock"></div>

  <div id="footerBlock"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using float?

Comment: Display:inline-block; on both elements might work for you as well.

Comment: I did try float and inline block. I've been running through a couple different variations and just can't get it to go side by side. It just keeps going on top of each other.

Comment: @Brandon Well obviously you didn't use `display: inline-block;` properly then... See my answer.

Comment: Sorry - I guess you're right. That did fix it but my dreamweaver doesn't show it correctly.. i had to import the code into a test webpage to see it. All this time I thought it was wrong..

Comment: @Brandon so stop using Dreamweaver, it sucks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make `.headerText` and `.headerImg` `display: inline-block;`, then that should do the trick.

```css
#wrap { 
  width: 800px; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

#headerBlock { 
  height: 200px; 
  background:  #776b68; 
}

div.headerText {
  display: inline-block;
}
div.headerImg {
  display: inline-block;
}
div.headerImg img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="headerBlock">
    <div class="headerText">Some text here</div>
    <div class="headerImg">
      <img src="/somepicturehere">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Ignore these, it's for future use-->
  <div id="leftBlock"></div>
  <div id="rightBlock"></div>
  <div id="footerBlock"></div>
</div>
```

And if you want to vertically align them, use `display: flex;` and `align-items: center;` on the container:

```css
#wrap { 
  width: 800px; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

#headerBlock { 
  height: 200px; 
  background:  #776b68; 
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

div.headerText {
  display: inline-block;
}
div.headerImg {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="headerBlock">
    <div class="headerText">Some text here</div>
    <div class="headerImg">
      <img src="/somepicturehere">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Ignore these, it's for future use-->
  <div id="leftBlock"></div>
  <div id="rightBlock"></div>
  <div id="footerBlock"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is what I used - thank you. I commented above but I guess the whole time I thought it wasn't working was because Dreamweaver wasn't showing it side by side. I had to upload it all onto a test webpage to actually see it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: flex` on the parent and that will create a row with the children side by side. Then you can also use other flex properties like `align-items` and `justify-content` to align horizontally/vertically.

```css
#wrap { 
width: 800px; 
margin: 0 auto; 
overflow: hidden;
float: left;
}

#headerBlock { 
height: 200px; 
background:  #776b68; 
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}

div.headerText {
text-align: justify;
}

div.headerImg img {
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
<div id="headerBlock">
    <div class="headerText">Some text here</div>
    <div class="headerImg"><img src="/somepicturehere">
    </div>
</div>

<!--Ignore these, it's for future use-->
<div id="leftBlock"></div>

<div id="rightBlock"></div>

<div id="footerBlock"></div>

</div>
```